# Annoying noise on Vaio S series when seeking music to other parts of the same song

Tags: sound, hardware, soundcard, noise

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Vaio S series computer (Model: SVS15136PGB).

When playing a music, everything is fine, but when seeking music (by seeking I mean when i click on the progress bar of the music time to go to other parts of the same song) a really annoying noise comes out of the sound card. The problem is the same on every music player (such as VLC and Banshee). I like my music library and I seek a lot. I really need help here!

I need to mention these:

- I have some mp3 songs that when I seek them, there is no noise!
- when i use my *SONY Bluetooth headphone SBH20* the noise is lower but the noise is still there!

Comment: What Vaio S series in particular do you have? Also, when you say seek, do you mean fast forwarding/going back to other parts of the same song, or moving to the next track (or both)?

Comment: thank you for your attention

my laptop model is: vaio svs15136PGB
no problem on moving to the next track, the problem is for example when clicking on the seek-bar to change the position of music, or seeking by keyboard.

Comment: by seeking i mean going back to other parts of the same song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer myself.
I tested the system and i found out that the songs that are encoded by Ogg Vorbis free code does not have any problem, so i downloaded [SoundConverter](http://soundconverter.org/) and converted my whole music library to Ogg Vorbis, it took some time, but worth it.
Now i do not have any noise problem on my music library, but of course by adding a new MP3 song there is the noise problem on that song.

**The main problem is not solved by this answer:**
*there is also one thing that i want to mention* for MP3 songs with noise when seeking: if i seek the MP3 song on all the possible positions, then there will be no noise by seeking the song (changing the song to another one and then again playing that song will reproduce the problem)!

Comment: I also use ogg vorbis instead of mp3 for my music. It's a great format. I can't see why most people still use mp3. :)

Comment: I like your opinion, ogg vorbis is great.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this, updating the driver,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa) help? Otherwise, have you tried making sure it's not something to do with your speakers/headphones?
Edit: I don't know what I'm talking about, so maybe you should wait with trying this until someone smarter suggests a better option ;)

Comment: no that did not work! and yes i'm sure that my speackers are just fine. I need to mention that I have some mp3 songs that when I seek them forward/backward, there is no noise!

Comment: I'n new in Linux world, and by updating the driver I learned some Linux stuff. well, thank you for guiding me.